# "undefined method visit" error with capybara, rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am trying to use [`capybara`](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara) with `rspec`.

*Gemfile*

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

According to the docs, i need to add `require 'capybara/rspec'` to *rails_helper.rb*, which i did:

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!    
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

Now when i run `bundle exec rspec`. i get:

```
Failure/Error: visit('/')

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::HomeFooters:0x000000035cc4b8>
```

The test is as follows:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "HomeFooters", type: :request do
  it "show proper links in footer" do 
    visit('/')
    page.should have_content("Jobs")
  end
end
```

How can i solve this error?

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`capybara` isn't suppose to be used with `type: :request`, it's `type: :feature`.